# How do I fix this SQL GROUP BY query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    dev.DeviceName, Count(dom.DomainID) AS CountOfDomains 
FROM 
    tblDevices dev 
JOIN 
    tblIPNumbers ip ON dev.DeviceName = ip.ServerName 
JOIN 
    tblDomains dom ON dom.IPNumberID = ip.IPNumberID  
WHERE 
    dom.PointerTo=0 
    AND dev.DeviceType='3' 
    AND (dev.[System]='32' OR dev.[System]='33') 
    AND dom.ClosedDate IS NULL AND dev.Active=1 
GROUP BY 
    dev.DeviceName 
ORDER BY 
    Count(dom.DomainID)
```

The tables look like:

```
tblDomains
==========
DomainID        int
IPNumberID      int
ClosedDate      datetime
PointerTo       int

tblIPNumbers
============
IPNumberID      int
ServerName      varchar(200)

tblDevices
==========
DeviceID        int
DeviceName      varchar(200)
System          varchar(10)
DeviceType      varchar(10)
Active          bit
```

Sample Data:

```
tblDomains:
===========
DomainID: 1234  IPNumberID: 1000    ClosedDate: NULL   PointerTo: 0

tblIPNumbers:
=============
IPNumberID: 1000  ServerName: WIN2008-01

tblDevices:
===========
DeviceID: 1    DeviceName: WIN2008-01     System: 32    Active: 1  DeviceType: 3
```

The problem is that if there are no rows in `tblDomains` that match an `IPNumberID` in `tblIPNumbers` I get no rows returned. I'd like the query to return a single row of `0` for `Count(dom.DomainID) AS CountOfDomains` in this case.

I've tried various combinations of `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins and it seems like a simple problem but my SQL-fu is low today.

Comment: What happens when you replace `JOIN tollon.tblDomains` with `LEFT JOIN tollon.tblDomains`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `LEFT JOIN`s instead of `JOIN`s, and also beware that when a `LEFT JOIN` doesn't find a matching row in the right table, it'll return `NULL`s for any field from that right table.

That means you issue comes from your `WHERE` clause that references `dom.pointerto` in a non-`NULL`-safe way, which will effectively void the benefits of the `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Ah, yes, so you probably want to specify `WHERE (dom.pointerto=0 OR dom.pointerto IS NULL) ...`

Comment: Combination of PP's and Romain's answer got this working. Thanks folks for the quick work.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `JOIN`s to `LEFT JOIN` and they'll include non-matching records as well.

Comment: really? do you get an error, or just the same behavior as your current?

Comment: It think it comes from the WHERE clause. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try Using outer join for table tbldomains

```
SELECT  
    dev.DeviceName, Count(dom.DomainID) AS CountOfDomains  
FROM  
    tblDevices dev  
JOIN  
   tblIPNumbers ip ON dev.DeviceName = ip.ServerName  
outer JOIN  
   tblDomains dom ON dom.IPNumberID = ip.IPNumberID   
WHERE  
    dom.pointerto=0  
    AND dev.devicetype='3'  
    AND (dev.[System]='32' OR dev.[System]='33')  
    AND dom.ClosedDate IS NULL AND dev.active=1  
GROUP BY  
    dev.DeviceName  
ORDER BY  
    Count(dom.DomainID)
```

Comment: Tip: add <pre><code> ... </code></pre> around your code to make it easier for others to read